# Is it possible to get JDBC pool attribute values using SNMP?

Tags: jdbc, jvm, snmp, pool, mib

I wonder whether it is possible to get the attribute values for the JDBC pools (Catalina,DataSource) by means of SNMP.

When I run

```
snmpwalk -On -Cc -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1:11111 .1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.145.3.163.1.1
```

I find no STRING variable holding the name of any JDBC pool, unlike the memory pools like `PS Eden Space` and others. Perhaps that is because either it is no possible or an additional (advanced) MIB file is required -- other than **`JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB`**.

Is it possible to do that using SNMP?

Thanx

P.D: I already know that is possible by means of a JMX/RMI connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK built-in SNMP agent does not support this.

If you wish to monitor JDBC pools via SNMP anyway, you'll need to run 3rd-party SNMP service like [SNMP4J](https://www.snmp4j.org/).